# Maven 3 has a new DSL formats for its POM. Is there a similar sort of format for Spring applicationcontext.xml files?

Tags: spring, dsl, maven-3, polyglot

In Maven 3 there are new DSL replacements for the POMs. See:
    http://polyglot.sonatype.org/groovy.html
for the wonderfully terse syntax.

Is there something similar that can be used for Spring applicationcontext.xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring 3 you may use Java-based container configuration, see [3.11 Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). It also plays well with [autodetection of components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning). To use these features instead of `applicationContext.xml`, add the following to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        ... package and class names to use for configuration ...
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

You may also configure `DispatcherServlet` in the same way - with `<init-param>` instead of `<context-param>`.

Comment: And you can also write this configuration in groovy, so it will much terse.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Grails Spring BeanBuilder, that provides a "groovy" way for the definition and configuration of Spring beans: http://www.grails.org/Spring+Bean+Builder